# GoogleSignIn ResultCode 0 when requesting the Game Scopes

Tags: android, google-api, google-signin

I can't get my Application to request the Game Scopes for access to the Google Play Games API. When requesting only DEFAULT_SIGN_IN it works. I already tried resigning my APP but to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
    var gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken("Server Client Id")
            .requestServerAuthCode("server ClientId")
            .requestEmail()
            .build();

    var mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
    startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Any help is appreciated!